# MATLAB funtion ginput in Android Open CV?

Tags: android, matlab, opencv

I am working on an image processing project to Android app. I have done `imread ();` , `imsize();` and `rgb2grey();` in android using opencv library. 
Now I am stuck in a function `ginput();` (Graphical input). This function helps to select ab object or point into the image by using mouse cursor. How can I use same function in Android Please help me how I can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need some solution in which you can drag your finger on android's screen and get all the points(x,y) from that area ? If it is so then you should be looking into gesture recognition in android.

Comment: actually I want to get pixel (x,y) of picture. I need pixel that I will touch or point out into the picture.

Comment: I'm sorry Im a bit late here, did you get the solution because to get a pixel you only have to touch the screen and gesture recognition functions of Android API will give you (x,y) coordinates of your touch location.